# Tiny web - can't get php.exe to return data

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, localhost

I can't get [Tiny web local server](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/download.php) to use php.exe to generate web pages - and learn PHP. I have followed the [instructions from the Ritlabs page](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/faq.php) and fully understand that Tiny web only uses console applications which write to STDOUT. I am using windows with ChromePortable as IE "security features" are desinged to stop this type of activity.

For Tiny Web to work the scripts in the cgi-bin folder must be properly associated with an executable AND the extensions should be present in the PATHEXT environment variable. Tiny Web reads file associations from the windows registry to execute the scripts. There are no config files for Tiny web. Execuatables MUST be console programs not GUI application. Some executables require options to load a script file and I tend to use batch files to get the parameters in order.

e.g. gawk.bat

```
:Change to current batch file location - with gawk.exe
cd /D "%~dp0"
:Run
gawk.exe -f "%1" %~2
```

This will run my "http://localhost:88/cgi-bin/test.awk" and generate dynamic web pages. I assumed that php.exe would work in a similar way if the php scripts are associated with a batch file:

e.g. php.bat

```
:Change to current batch file location - with php.exe
cd /D "%~dp0"
:Run
php.exe -f "%1" -- %~2
```

My test.php script contains:

```
<?php echo "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";?>
<?php echo "Hello World - from PHP";?>
```

However, this gives me an error: "CGI script /cgi-bin/test.php returned nothing", although it runs perfectly at the DOS command prompt! I tried running .php with php-cgi.exe "%1" and this gave the same server error, and at the command line prepends a header then prints as expected.

I don't want (don't have persissions) to install ISS or any other software. It is ironic that I am struggling to run php cgi scripts with Tiny web, but can generate dynamic pages with COMSPEC, LUA51.EXE, GSLSHELL.EXE, CSCRIPT.EXE, GAWK.EXE and even SQLITE3.EXE!

Q1. Have I just got the wrong test.php?

Q2. How should I process php files to get results back to Tiny web via STDOUT?

Q3. To make this portable I would love to make temporary file associates for the environment around Tiny.exe. I cold use assoc and ftype in my run.bat that launches Tiny web, if I had admin privilages. Any clues in the sub-admin world of windows at your work place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you analyze [TinyWeb source code](https://github.com/maximmasiutin/TinyWeb), it runs scripts in the `/cgi-bin/` the following way:

If the extension is `.exe`, it runs it straight. Otherwise, it finds an executable for this type of file extension using [Windows Win32 API call `FindExecutable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Then, if the `.exe` executable have been found for this file extension, it runs with this executable and passes your script path as the first command-line parameter.

To check whether there is an executable associated with your script extension, run cmd.exe in the `cgi-bin` folder and type the name of your script from the command line. It should give output to the screen. I don’t have PHP installed on my Windows machine, but I have Perl, and if I type myscript.pl, it gives output to the screen, so it confirms that `FindExecutable()` finds it. Also, when I type `perl.exe myscript.pl`, it also produces the correct output – this is how TinyWeb runs it. What happens when you run `cmd.exe` and type `test.php`? Does it print the desired output? By the way, I didn’t hear that anybody has been able to run TinyWeb with PHP. But if you type `test.php` from the command line and `php.exe test.php` works, then TinyWeb will run your PHP script.